# QT UDP сокет получение данных в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, qt, udp

Приветствую.

Проблема в следующем- надо запустить в отдельном потоке прослушивание **UDP сокета** с тайм аутом в n секунд, после чего в основном потоке отправить данные по другому **UDP сокету**.

Последовательность именно такая, чтобы не пропустить принимаемый пакет. Вопрос, как это сделать?

Вариант с методом класса `QAbstractSocket::waitForReadyRead()` отпадает, т.к. он нестабильно работает на Windows. Версия **QT 5.8.0**.

Примерный псевдокод (Скорее всего, есть средства QT, которые помогут выполнить эти действия куда быстрее и изящнее, но т.к. я новичок в QT, я их не знаю):

```
QDatagram Функция Прием_Данных  
  Пока i < Timeout  
    считать данные с сокета 
    Если данные есть  
      вернуть QDatagram  
    Конец  
    i+=100;  
    Остановить процесс на 100 мс  
  Конец  
  вернуть QDatagram  
Конец  

Основная функция  
  В отдельном потоке запустить Прием_Данных
  Отправить данные на устройство  
  Ожидать выполнение функции Прем_Данных 
Конец
```

Comment: А из за чего требование на задержки по времени ? Сокет позволяет спать до тех пор пока данные не придут и проснуться моментально когда они есть. Если используется чтение нескольких сокетов в одном потоке, то используются функции select (или epoll) для ожидания данных сразу с нескоких сокетов. функция возвращает управление когда данные доступны и вы видите с какого сокета они

Comment: Ну, говорю, я же новичок и я не знаю очень многого. Мне бы пример кода =/
Сокет, с которого происходит считывание, всего один

Comment: чувствую, что очередная XY проблема... какая всё же задача X? чтобы при получении датаграммы основной EventLoop не подвешивался в ожидании, а если ничего не пришло за Timeout секунд вывести ошибку? тогда здесь даже отдельный поток не нужен — всё делается через сигналы +QTimer.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а как? Через сигнал `readyRead()`? Если да, то как тогда это должно выглядеть? В смысле, как привязать `readyRead()` к конкретному сокету? Через `connect(UDP_Receiver, SIGNAL(readyRead(), this, SLOT(Receive()))`? Или должно быть еще что- то?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, и как в таком случае реализовать тайм аут чтения?

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov, да, именно так в самом простом варианте... таймаут — через отдельный QTimer... сейчас что-нибудь набросаю...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, жду)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Описание

Пример слушает UDP порт `localhost:50080`, логирует всё, что в него пришло, модифицирует сообщение ставя перед ним `Hey, I've received a message:` и отсылает на `localhost:50081`. Если нет сообщений в течении 5 секунд — приложение завершается.

#### Код

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QTime>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QByteArray>
#include <QtNetwork/QUdpSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>

#include <stdint.h>

class QUdpSocketCat: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QUdpSocket *in;
  QUdpSocket *out;
  QTimer *timer;
public:
  explicit QUdpSocketCat(QObject *parent=0):
    QObject(parent)
  {
    in = new QUdpSocket(this);
    out = new QUdpSocket(this);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    // connection data
    in->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 50080);
    out->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 50081);
    // connect signal on receiving new data
    connect (in, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(catData()));

    // setup timer
    timer->start(5000);
    connect (timer, &QTimer::timeout, [] () {
      qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString()
               << "I'm so lonely... goodbye cruel world...";
      QCoreApplication::instance()->exit();
    });

    qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString()
             << "Starting";
  }

protected slots:
  void catData () {
    while (in->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
      QByteArray datagram;
      datagram.resize(in->pendingDatagramSize());
      QHostAddress sender;
      quint16 senderPort;
      in->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &sender, &senderPort);

      // Log stuff
      qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString()
               << QString("I'm so happy! I've received a message from my dear friend %1:%2| %3.")
                          .arg(sender.toString()).arg(senderPort).arg(QString::fromLocal8Bit(datagram));

      // Modify the datagramm
      QByteArray out_datagram = "Hey, I've received a message: ";
      out_datagram.append(datagram);
      // send out the datagramm
      out->write(out_datagram.data());

      // restart the timer
      timer->start(5000);
    }
  }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QUdpSocketCat cat;

  return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

#### Запуск

В одном терминале запускаем прослушивание порта 50081:

```
netcat -u -l -p 50081 localhost
```

Во втором сам саму программу и запись в порт  (разбит на строки для удобства):

```
./qunetcat &
(sleep 2; echo "Hello there" | netcat -u --close localhost 50080) 
&& wait
```

Примечание: используется GNU'тый netcat. У BSD'яшного и классического ключи могут отличаться.

#### Вывод

```
[1] 11988
"15:45:12" Starting
"15:45:14" "I'm so happy! I've received a message from my dear friend 127.0.0.1:41603| Hello there\n."
"15:45:18" I'm so lonely... goodbye cruel world...
[1]+  Done
```

Как видно, первая и последняя строки от bash'а, дальше вывод о запуске и получении сообщения через две секунды. Затем завершение через 5.

Во втором терминале имеем ожидаемую строку:

```
Hey, I've received a message: Hello there
```